# Obtain void* pointer to content of boost::any

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I am using an external library that has a method which accepts a void*

I want this void* to point to an object contained within a boost::any object.

**Is it possible to get at the address of the content of a boost::any object?**

I'm trying to play with myAny.content but no luck so far! I'm hoping some combination of dynamic_cast or unsafe_any_cast will give me what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, unfortunately; `boost::any_cast` will refuse the cast if the type is distinct from the contained type.

If you're willing to use an unsupported internal hack, the [current version of the header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/any.hpp) has an undocumented and unsupported function `boost::unsafe_any_cast` which (as its name suggests) bypasses the type check performed by `boost::any_cast`:

```
boost::any any_value(value);
void *content = boost::unsafe_any_cast<void *>(&any_value);
```

The header has this to say about `unsafe_any_cast`:

```
// Note: The "unsafe" versions of any_cast are not part of the
// public interface and may be removed at any time. They are
// required where we know what type is stored in the any and can't
// use typeid() comparison, e.g., when our types may travel across
// different shared libraries.
```

Comment: This should be part of the documented interface, so `boost::any` could be used with legacy code that uses `void*`. Saddest of all, `std::experimental::any` doesn't seem to even have an `unsafe_any_cast`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `boost::any_cast` to get a pointer to the underlying type (provided you know it at compile time).

```
boost::any any_i(5);

int* pi = boost::any_cast<int>(&any_i);
*pi = 6;

void* vpi = pi;
```

Comment: What is this code actually doing? It looks like it is casting the address itself into an int. How come that works?

Comment: That's what `boost::any_cast` does.  It has similar semantics as `dynamic_cast`.  In this case, casting to an `int*` will succeed, because the underlying type stored is an int.  Casing to some other pointer type (say `float*`), would result in a `nullptr` being returned.  Casting to a reference type will either succeed, or throw a `boost::bad_any_cast` exception.  `boost::any` works only on exact type matches, it uses `typeid` for matching if I recall correctly.